# Word replacing javascript for one specific browser

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript that is going to replace one word but only if the page is being displayed by a certain browser.

For the word replacement I came up with this code:

```
window.onload = clear;
function clear() {
   document.body.innerHTML = 
      document.body.innerHTML.replace(/replaceitemid/g,  'title');
```

and it's working great but now I want this to be loaded only if the `navigator.userAgent` or `navigator.appVersion = IngameBrowser`. I'm looking for a simplest solution, nothing fancy.

I did it! I will just post the working version if someone is ever going to look for similar thing

```
browsername=navigator.appVersion;
if (browsername.indexOf("IngameBrowser")!=-1) {browsername="AI"};
if (browsername=="AI") {window.onload = clear;
function clear() {
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/replaceitemid/g,  'title');} };
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple conditional before setting the body work?  In other words: `if(navigator.appVersion === IngameBrowser){//what you wrote}`

Answer (score 0):

Check out Bowser: https://github.com/ded/bowser

Example:

```
if (bowser.msie && bowser.version <= 6) {
  alert('Hello China');
}
```

Comment: Can you please put a small description of what that does?  `bowser` I mean.

Comment: Well, let's say you want to replace only if the browser is Internet Explorer. You'd do: function clear(){ if(bowser.msie) //replace code here }

Comment: No, I mean please edit your question so that it isn't just a bare link.  Add the description there.

Comment: Hummm... From the website: A Browser detector. Because sometimes, there is no other way, and not even good modern browsers always provide good feature detection mechanisms.